# The size of roots

Tags: math-mode, symbols, formatting

I can't get to the root of this problem: I need the second root to be the same height as the first one

```
$\sqrt{F} \: \sqrt{F_{x_x}}$
```

I know I can use `\vphantom`, but I don't know how.

Comment: Just add `\vphantom{F_{x_x}}` to the first square root: `\sqrt{F\vphantom{F_{x_x}}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I want to make the second root "smaller" (small as the first root)?

Comment: @user32680 With `amsmath` loaded you can do `$\sqrt{F} \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{F_{x_x}}}$`.

Comment: -1 for the abysmal pun. ... ok, just kidding.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Aligning square roots in the same formula requires some work if the symbols under the square root are not uniform in height and depth.

You can either add a phantom to the first square root or smash the bottom of the second one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{F} + \sqrt{F_{x_x}}$  % original

\medskip

$\sqrt{F\vphantom{F_{x_x}}} + \sqrt{F_{x_x}}$ % phantom

\medskip

$\sqrt{F} + \sqrt{\smash[b]{F_{x_x}}}$ % smash

\end{document}
```

[image]